# Double Tap Error while implementing Universal Image Loader and ImageViewTouch

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, pinchzoom, universal-image-loader

I am implementing a photo gallery in my app, so I used Nostras famous Universal Image Loader.
However, it does not provide zoom in/out and double tap features which are currently the norm with photos inside handsets.

For this reason I implemented the ImageViewTouch library and replaced my ImageView with ImageViewTouch and now I am able to get the zoom in and out features on my desired photo.

XML :

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

inside my Activity :

```
ImageViewTouch imageView = (ImageViewTouch) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN);
```

Unfortunately, when I double tap, I am getting a black screen. (the app does not freez or anything) The image suddenly turns into black and I have to scroll left or right (or press back) to get another image, or go back to my previous screen.

Has anybody had this issue before ?
I am not limited to use ImageViewTouch. If there is any other library that solves the case, I am open to ideas.

Comment: Alternative: PhotoView, gesture-image-view

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm getting the same issue

Comment: It seems that for me, setting the layout_width and height to fill_parent solved the issue. I can't imagine that will work for everyone though

Comment: PhotoView works great with Universal Image Loader